# initializing Kronecker delta matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a matrix of the form delta(i,j+1), where delta means the Kronecker delta using matlab.

I've tried looking online and couldn't find a function that does that

I would like to do it without loops and in the most compact why possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the dimension of your matrix.

```
v = ones(n,1);
A = diag(v, -1);
```